# Alias for frequently repeated expression

Tags: mysql

I have a table of places like this

```
   placeid    offset1  effectivetill1         offset2  effectivetill2
   1          3600     2014-01-05 10:23:13    0        2014-07-05 10:23:13
   2          -7200    2014-01-05 10:23:13    -3600    2014-07-05 10:23:13
```

I run a very big query that needs to work with local time for each place. Therefore if
"ts" is the UTC timestamp for now, and "datetime" is current UTC date-time,  I use the following formula to find local time:

```
  IF(effectivetill1='0000-00-00' OR effectivetill1>=datetime, ts+offset1, 
    IF(effectivetill2>=datetime, ts+offset2, 0)
  )
```

So I need to repeat the above code several times in my query which is stupid for both computation and code readability.

Is there anyway that I can define localtime once in my query and then use it multiple times?

Thanks.

Comment: what kind of error you getting..

Comment: I'm not getting any error. I just want to avoid repeating the above code in my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you would be using the same variable at each row level,

Try:

```
@ts_with_offset:=IF( effectivetill1 = '0000-00-00' OR 
                     effectivetill1 >= datetime, 
                     ts + offset1, 
                     IF( effectivetill2 >= datetime, ts + offset2, 0 )
                 ) as name_of_this_expression
```

And use the variable `@ts_with_offset` to fetch other values based on this value or something like that.

```
if ( @ts_with_offset >= now(), true, false ) as matched
```

Note that, when using group functions in the query, this way of using variables is not going to work.